# How to store variables in a db and then interpolate them on retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, interpolation

I have in my mysql db the following value for the 'statement' field:
on the $x day of $month

Then when i fetch it out of the db, I want to be able to define the variables and then echo out the statement with the variables being interpolated.
like this:

```
$x = '4th';
$month = 'july';
// query and fetch..
$sentence = $result['statement'];
echo $sentence;  // I want this to read 'on the 4th day of july'
```

the problem is all that i get is 'on the $x day of $month'.

I've tried putting quotes and double quotes around things, but just can't figure out how do to this.

Comment: Can you add the DB fetching stuff to your code aswell, please?

Comment: echo "on the ".$x." day of ".$month;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to put variable name into database?
You have two options:

**Ugly and dirty**

Save to database:
'Something on'.$x.' day of '.$month.' will happen';

To call it: 
`echo eval($sentence);`

Eval will execute everything what you will give so it's very unsafe.

**Nice and more safe:**

Save to database:
Something on %s day of %s will happen

To call it: 
`echo sprintf($sentence, $x, $month);`

[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) will format string and "validate" variables for you. For example if you will put %d in sentence then [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) will want a integer there.